# GCP Dataproc - cyrillic characters not displaying correctly in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, cyrillic

I have a weird problem with Python.

If I run this script with Cyrillic words on my local python machine, it works correctly as it should. However, if I run it on Dataproc as a Spark job, it will print something very different.

```py
str1 = 'Кровати'
print(str1)
```

output on my local python is `Кровати`
on Dataproc it is `ÐÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°ÑÐ¸`

This is the core of the problem. The real reason why I need this is that I have lot of words in Russian in the data and then comparison between the loaded data from BQ and the words in config doesn't work even if the strings should be the same.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you test locally on pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the encoding of your source code, on your local machine the default encoding is set correctly, but it is different from Dataproc PySpark's default. You can follow https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ to explicitly set the encoding of your source code.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work :/
I have added 
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
but the results are the same when comaparing my local output vs dataproc output

Comment: What if you don't print the string out which will use Dataproc's default encoding, you save it into a file?